# error ORA-00923

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

I am getting the following error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" while executing the query, NOTE: already am using this query with different tables and its working ,so please i need your help :)

---

```
LOAD * ,
date(POST_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') as VOU_POST_DATE,
date(CREATED_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') as VOU_CREATED_DATE,
year (POST_DATE) as VOU_POST_YEAR ,
month (POST_DATE) as VOU_POST_MONTH,
day (POST_DATE) as VOU_POST_DAY, 
year (CREATED_DATE) as VOU_CREATED_YEAR ,
month (CREATED_DATE) as VOU_CREATED_MONTH,
day (CREATED_DATE) as VOU_CREATED_DAY;

Select 
t.QTY as VOU_QTY,
t.COST as VOU_COST,
t.PRICE as VOU_PRICE,
t.QTY*t.COST as VOU_EXT_COST,
t.QTY*t.PRICE as VOU_EXT_PRICE,
t.ITEM_SID,
o.STORE_NO as VOU_STORE_NO,
o.VOU_NO,
o.VOU_TYPE, 
o.VOU_CLASS,
o.VEND_CODE as VOU_VEND_CODE,
o.SLIP_FLAG,
o.TO_NO,
o.REF_VOU_SID,
o.CREATED_DATE,
o.POST_DATE,
o.SLIP_FLAG as SLIP_FLAGS,
o.VERIFIED,
st.QTY as TRANS_OUT_QTY
s.OUT_STORE_NO as SLIP_OUT_STORE,
s.IN_STORE_NO as SLIP_IN_STORE,


CASE
when o.VEND_CODE is not NULL
and o.TO_NO is NULL 
then t.QTY
else 0
end CMP_RCVD_QTY,


CASE
when o.VEND_CODE is NULL 
and o.TO_NO is not NULL 
then t.QTY
else 0
end FST_RCVD_QTY,


CASE
when o.VEND_CODE is NULL 
and o.TO_NO is NULL 
then t.QTY
else 0
end TRANS_IN_QTY,

CASE
when o.VOU_CLASS=2 
then t.QTY
else 0
end ASN_QTY,

from VOUCHER o
join VOU_ITEM t
on o.VOU_SID = t.VOU_SID 

Join SLIP s
on s.VOU_SID = o.VOU_SID 

join  SLIP_ITEM st
on st.ITEM_SID = t.ITEM_SID
where 
o.HELD=0 and o.REF_VOU_SID is NULL;
```

Comment: How are you using the **same** query with **different** tables? That doesn't make much sense. Do you mean "similar" query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `,` after `TRANS_OUT_QTY`

> ```
> o.VERIFIED,
> st.QTY as TRANS_OUT_QTY
> s.OUT_STORE_NO as SLIP_OUT_STORE,
> ```

and remove `,` before from clause.

> ```
> CASE
> when o.VOU_CLASS=2 
> then t.QTY
> else 0
> end ASN_QTY,
>
> from VOUCHER o
> join VOU_ITEM t
> on o.VOU_SID = t.VOU_SID
> ```

Oracle expects `FROM` keyword where we end our comma separated column-list. As you can see, you have forgotten to type `,` after  `st.QTY as TRANS_OUT_QTY` it expects `FROM` clause right after it hence the error `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`.

Once you fix the first syntax error you will be hit by another error called `ORA-00936: missing expression` as you have provided extra `,` after `end ASN_QTY,` which indicates there are more expressions after the `,` but there are not.